Meaning of “Put itself in the wrong”
I would like to ask for help with understanding of “Put itself in the wrong”.
The whole sentence is “With propensity to put itself in the wrong, he only informed us very brifely.
What is the meaning of “Put itself in the wrong”? I hasn’t found any idiom, only found that “in the wrong” means to be responsible for something wrong, but this does not makes sense to me.
CONTEXT UPDATE:
it’s a book from 2013 from famous British historiam about World War. The sentence in the is “With a lack of attention to detail and a propensity to put itself in the wrong which was going to mark the whole affair, the Foreign Ministry only informed the other countries with an interest in Africa after the fact,……”
I will be happy for any ideas.
Thanks

Where did you hear or see this? It is very bad English, and is meaningless.

Please edit to share more context. It doesn't make sense to us either, or at least we can guess at the meaning in spite of the words used. "In the wrong" isn't usually combined with "put"; "propensity" would usually have an article; there's no clear antecedent to "itself" (though I fear it's either "he" or "us," in which case "it" is the wrong choice); and while "inform ... briefly" isn't really objectionable, it doesn't sound like the best choice. Perhaps context will make more sense of this, but I suspect it's best ignored.

@AndyBonner it’s a book from 2013 from famous British historiam about World War. The sentence in the is “With a lack of attention to detail and a propensity to put itself in the wrong which was going to mark the whole affair, the Foreign Ministry only informed the other countries with an interest in Africa after the fact,,……”

Maybe it's more common in Britain, but we might very well say that someone put themselves in the wrong by some act or omission. The issue is Ravi has put himself in the wrong by taking Nugget's tantrum personally and lashing out the way he would if an adult had said all those things. Forum discussion about British TV soap, April 2023

What is the book? It is good form, even if not specifically required here, to provide a source.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany - It’s from War that ended peace by Margaret MacMillan

@VilemRousi Thanks, Chapter 15, and it's the German Foreign Ministry that's the subject.

Please fix the quote in your question.

The Foreign Ministry ('it' because it's a government body, not a person) had 'put itself in the wrong' by not informing other countries of some planned action in advance. That is, it had made itself liable to be accused of wrongdoing.

It means that the Foreign Ministry was sloppy ("lack of attention to detail") and frequently was the cause of undesirable consequences ("with propensity to put itself in the wrong") during the events in question ("was going to mark the whole affair"), in the estimation of the author.
When someone is "in the wrong" they are responsible for something bad that happened, such as a conflict.

There is the somewhat old-fashioned expression "to put oneself in the wrong", though it is still being used today in litrachuh.

I felt that I had put myself in the wrong by opening a drawer which they had locked.

--Arthur Conan Doyle, The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes
With "it" as the reflexive object of the verb, some organization would have to be the actor, but your sentence has he. Perhaps you misheard himself?

"Still being used today"? Doyle hardly counts as "today." A halfhearted ngram investigation yields no 21st-century usages in a few minutes, just reprints of Anthony Trollope, Kierkegaard, etc.

@AndyBonner Doyle is not my example of it still being used today, though I realize the answer might make it look that way. He's cited to represent  the "somewhat old-fashioned".

If you do a Google Books search you'll find some 21st century examples. As I sought to imply with "in litrachuh", the collocation is rarified these days.

'in litrachuh' - I wish you hadn't done that.

@TimR, I’ve updated the context in the input. There is really itself in the sentence - reffering ti Ministry so it’s relevant to your example with onself.

@TimR the phrase you mentioned - “ to put oneself in the wrong” - it means something like - to confuse oneself?

@VilemRousi - to put yourself in the wrong is to do something which is stupid or mistaken, likely to lead to trouble for yourself, or likely to be criticised, or which will put you at a disadvantage in an easily-foreseen argument or disagreement.

Thank you @MichaelHarvey

This construct may not be frequently written in the 21st century, but it is most assuredly still being frequently read in the 21st century.

@barbecue   I agree with you about the construction being read nowadays even if it is not being spoken (Robert Louis Stevenson, for example, uses it, and he has stood the test of time) but how does one document the fact that people are reading authors who used the construction?

@MichaelHarvey In defense of "litrachuh", the construction has not had much traction in AmE.  But mea culpa.
